# How do I insert an Angular Component in CSS grid

Tags: css, angular, typescript, css-grid

I'm learning Angular, and I'm working on a project ,in which, I need to use a CSS grid layout. However, I'm trying to find a way to insert a component inside a grid with given `grid-area`.

I tried to do this, `<app-slots></app-slots>`, in `app.component.html` but the component `<app-slots>` was counted as one grid place only; even though, it's 42 places.

**slots.component.html:**

`<div class="abc" *ngFor="let in of getArrayOfNumbers(42) ;let i = index" [style.grid-row] = "i+1" style = "height:20px"  > {{in}} </div>`

**slots.component.ts:**

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-slots',
      templateUrl: './slots.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['../../app.component.css']
    })
    export class SlotsComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        
      }
    
      getArrayOfNumbers(x: number){
        var slots:number[] = [];
        var a: number = x;
        
        while(x != 0){
          slots.push(x);
          x--;
        }
        return slots;
      }
    
    }
```

**Note: If something is not clear please tell me to add more info**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you just insert the component   between your  tags (instead of {{in}}), then send whatever updating variables from the .ts file through that using angular's binding feature ?

[two way binding](https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7#:%7E:text=%20Angular%20%E2%80%94%20Custom%20two%20way%20data%20binding,the%20event%E2%80%99s%20name%20amountChange.%20If%20the...%20More%20)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess this is not the problem; the problem is that `<app-slots>` have multiple divs. All of these divs go into one grid place. I want each div to be in  its own place by using the component.

Comment: you need to insert  42 instances of a component into a grid such as this ?  https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid

Comment: or the app slots component has a grid of 42 and you need to insert it into multiple divs?

Comment: Well, if I don't use component it works fine, which means I put that div that is in `slots.component.html` into `app.component.html`. However, I need to use a separate component for this.

Comment: is your component registered in the app.module?